# Using Automapper to change Collection

Tags: c#, automapper, icollection

I have two models in C# that have a one to many relation:

```
public class Make
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Model> Models { get; set; }
}

public class Model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Make Make { get; set; }
    public int MakeId { get; set; }
}
```

and the DTO as follows:

```
public class MakeDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ModelId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Models> Models { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using Automapper to map DTO in update operation, the problem is add/remove the collection are working fine but *adding new items* and *update the existing items* not working.

```
public AutoMapperProfile()
{

    CreateMap<MakeDto, Make>()
        .ForMember(m => m.Id, opt => opt.Ignore())
        .ForMember(m => m.Model, opt => opt.Ignore())
        .AfterMap((dt, m) =>
        {

            // Remove Model
            var removedModel = m.Model.Where(x => !dt.Model.Any(f => f.Id == x.Id)).ToList();
            foreach (var m in removedModel)
                m.Model.Remove(m);

            // Add new Model
            var addedModel = dt.Model.Where(x => !m.Model.
            Any(f => f.Id == x.Id))
            .Select(x => new Model
            {
                Id = dt.Id,
                Name = x.Name
            })
            .ToList();            
            foreach (var m in addedModel)
                m.Model.Add(m);


        }).AfterMap((dt, m) =>
        {
            //Update Model
            m.Model = m.Model.Where(x => dt.Model.Any(f => f.Id == x.Id))
            .Select(x => new Model
            {
                Name = dt.Model.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == x.Id).Name,
            }).ToList();
        });
}
```

Comment: Try AutoMapper.Collection.

Comment: I couldn't fit it to m\y needs.

Comment: When mapping to an existing collection, the destination collection is cleared first. Without AutoMapper.Collection, you'd have to ignore the collection properties and map them yourself. So maybe give it another try :)

Comment: I don't know why mapper.collection remove all records from destination collection and add new ones. weird!

Comment: You're doing smth wrong. [AM.Collection](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection) does what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to answer my question and for future readers, I used Automapper.Collection as follows:

```
        var mapper = new MapperConfiguration(
            cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddCollectionMappers();
                cfg.CreateMap<MakeDto, Make>()
                    .EqualityComparison((src, dst) => src.Id == dst.Id);
                cfg.CreateMap<Model, Model>()
                    .ForMember(x => x.Make, opt => opt.Ignore())
                    .EqualityComparison((src, dst) => src.Id == dst.Id);
            })
            .CreateMapper();
        mapper.Map<MakeDto, Make>(makeDto, make);
        await _unitOfWork.CompleteAsync();
```

also if interested, see this [link](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection/issues/114)